# Why is “tribo” feminine?

Tags: etimologia, substantivos, gênero

Since it ends in **o**, you'd expect it to be masculine. Additionally, it's not a contraction of an originally feminine noun such as *foto* < *fotografia*. The dictionary indicates nothing too significant of its etymology:

> lat. tribus,us 'tribo, divisão do povo romano'

This being the case, how did the noun *tribo* come to be feminine?

Comment: Portuguese “*tribo*” comes from Latin “*tribus* and “*tribus*” is/was feminine in latin too, so you could say that Portuguese “*tribo*” is feminine because its antecedent, “*tribus*” was/is also feminine, but I believe you seek for a deeper explanation. I just don't know if an explanation that has to go through Latin and very possibly PIE fits in Portuguese StackExchange. .By the way, the Latin word “*tribus*” has many meanings, for what I've seen.

Comment: @Schilive It’s because of medieval hesitation that settled into the historical gender, but has not always been that way. See below.

Comment: Tribo isn't the only feminine noun ending in "o".  There are many more.  Likewise, "carisma" isn't the only masculine noun ending in "a".

Comment: @Centaurus, and there's also nouns ending in “a” or “o” that can be masculine or feminine, like “caixa” and sorta “macho”, since there's “macha”, but it's not very used. Endings can be tricky.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is Latin. The longer answer is quite a bit more nuanced.

The various fourth-declension *-us* feminines in Latin like *tribus* and
*manus* were much more apt to retain their original gender than the rather
uncommon second-declension *-us* feminines were.  That is why we have *a mão,
as mães* from the Latin fourth-declension feminine *manus*.

Similarly,
Latin *tribus* also stayed feminine in ***most*** Romance, including in
modern Portuguese where it’s always feminine *a tribo* today, like in *as doze
tribos de Israel* or in *as tribos urbanas*.

In contrast, **second**-declension Latin *-us* feminines usually became masculines,
especially in Iberia. The Latin word *methodus* was a second-declension
feminine that became masculine in modern Portuguese *o método* and Spanish
*el método*. Yet in France it remained feminine: modern French has *la
méthode*. Other second-declension feminines that became masculines today
include *humus* becoming *húmus, humo*.

But *tribus* is from the fourth declension not the second, and so it
**largely** retained its original gender.  It stayed feminine and became *la
tribu* in all three of French, Spanish, and Asturian, and is now *la tribù*
in modern Italian.  However, in Catalan and Galician, a language very
closely related to Portuguese, it became masculine, producing ***o** tribo*
in Galician and *el tribu* in Catalan.

The split between Portuguese and Galician provides your first visible
indication that there’s a much more interesting story behind all this.
That is, you can find no end of old examples where
Portuguese uses *o tribo* not *a tribo*.  Why is that?  For that matter,
you can even find it used in the masculine today from time to time,
although this is not considered standard Portuguese any longer.

But it once was! Or at least, **could** be.

In [A categoria gramatical de género do português antigo ao português
actual](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/19129463.pdf) Maria Carmen de Frias
e Gouveia da Universidade de Coimbra at various points writes:

> Recolhi muitos vocábulos que mudaram de género do período arcaico para o
> português actual: *afronto, alcachofra, aleijão, ametisto, apostema, bacio,
> banco roto, cisma, clima, cometa, cornas, dote, esfinge, espinafre, estige,
> estratagema, fantasma, hipérbole, íbis, mapa, mar, metamorfose, pirâmide
> (pirames), planeta, retrete, rim, rouba,* etc. Variaram, desde cedo: *árvore,
> cárcere, fim, teiró, tribo,* entre outras. Curiosamente, retomaram o género
> etimológico, por exemplo, *andorinha, diocese* (esporadicamente masculino na
> época medieval, como se verá) e *tribo*.

...

> *Árvore* era ainda de género masculino em Duarte Nunes de Leão, não obstante
> o feminino ter surgido em época muito mais recuada: «.., dizemos este
> método, este dote, este paul, este tribo, este nariz, este árvore [...]»
> (Leão: cap. VII, 224). O feminino definitivo é, portanto, posterior a
> finais do século XVI.

> *Tribo*, palavra hoje feminina, sofreu hesitação de género, mesmo ao longo de
> século XVII. Vieira (Ali, 1964: 70) usa-a nos dois géneros: «De **huma tribo
> a outra tribo**» (*Sermões*, 8, 264 e «Ajuntou **todos os tribos** que poude»
> (Ibidem, 9, 412). Camões empregou-a como masculina: «**o tribo** ilustre»
> (Lusíadas, III, 140).

> Como se pode ver por estes exemplos, as razões que levaram à mudança do
> género dos vocábulos podem ser, efectivamente, de variada ordem: alguns,
> como *cometa, fantasma, planeta* ou *tribo* (e eventualmente *dia*) viram o
> seu género alterado devido á terminação, (mesmo *guia* e *espia* que,
> embora aplicados a homens, eram femininos em Castilho e Vieira),
> recuperando mais tarde, possivelmente por influência culta, o género
> etimológico; outros sofreram mudança por associação com o sexo da pessoa de
> que são atributo; outros ainda, adquiriram o género que tinham na língua
> através da qual entraram em Português ou por analogia com outros vocábulos
> como teria acontecido com *dote*, agora masculino.

...

> Por outro lado, provou-se que, em vários casos, a hesitação no emprego do
> género gramatical, com a consequente coexistência de formas, levou – como
> ainda hoje acontece – a uma mudança.. O mesmo sucede com outros vocábulos,
> como as palavras de género duvidoso, podendo ocorrer uma futura alteração,
> como se anuncia já na forma *grama*, que conhece o uso erudito (o
> masculino) e o feminino que tende a fixar-se por influência da terminação.
> No entanto, não pode afirmar-se com toda a segurança que essa coexistência,
> numa determinada época, de uma forma masculina e outra feminina leve
> automaticamente a uma mudança, ou ao abandono de uma forma em favor de
> outra. Registaram-se casos, por exemplo, em que houve coexistência de
> formas, uma delas mais evoluída em relação ao étimo, e voltou-se, depois,
> ao género etimológico (como com *cometa, tribo,* etc.) e o inverso (*dote,
> diocese*, entre outros exemplos).

I encourage you to read her paper. She also provides a long list of academic references for further study.

By the way, some of these languages that use *-u* forms today have older,
obsolete *-o* versions, or else the other way around. Others have it as an
invariant that has no plural inflection, as in Sardinian where you can have
*tribù nuraghesas*, with feminine plural concord but an unchanging nominal
form.

Such unchanging nominals in *-u(s)* can also be found from time
to time in Spanish, such as in  *el/los humus* and *el/los virus*. Those two were originally
feminine and neuter but in the second-declension in Latin, not masculine like today.

Comment: Interesting, your answer. I've heard that there was a time in which the Latin and Greek were considered better and that's what made so many words go back into its etymological form, like “*flor*” that was “*chor*” or “*fror*”, i.e., “*flōs*” > “*flōrem*” > “*fror*” or “*chor*” > “*flor*”. I know that that existed in Spanish, but do you know if it also happened with Portuguese? I just know that there was a lot of borrowing from Latin and Greek in that time, mainly Latin, and that a lot of Spanish words went back into its original/etymological form.

Comment: @Schilive I do not know that this was deliberate like the things you speak of. There was a period in all (applicable) European languages after the so-called Dark Ages when scholars deliberately reintroduced forms that were much closer to the Latin originals than what they had been left with after many centuries had worn down the originals. This happened in Portuguese and Spanish and English too via its French imports. Think *frio* versus *frígido*.

Comment: Tchrist, I mean that that reintroducing could have influenced the gender of some words that were “regularized”.

Comment: @Schilive Yes, the paper mentions "alguns, como *cometa, fantasma, planeta* ou *tribo* (e eventualmente *dia*) viram o seu género alterado devido á terminação, (mesmo *guia* e *espia* que, embora aplicados a homens, eram femininos em Castilho e Vieira), **recuperando mais tarde, *possivelmente por influência culta*, o género etimológico**". So there have been some “educated” influence in the recovery of the original gender.

Comment: Nitpicking here: tribu is not a masculine word in Catalan. It's "la tribu" https://dlc.iec.cat/Results?DecEntradaText=tribu&AllInfoMorf=False&OperEntrada=0&OperDef=0&OperEx=0&OperSubEntrada=0&OperAreaTematica=0&InfoMorfType=0&OperCatGram=False&AccentSen=False&CurrentPage=0&refineSearch=0&Actualitzacions=False# . You might be confusing it with "tribú" which is masculine but doesn't descend from tribus but tribunus, and it means tribune (the roman magistrature).

Comment: @Pere, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tribu#Catalan and http://www.catalandictionary.org/en/search/ say something else. I am not saying you're wrong, since I don't know Catalan -- my grandmother does, but that it looks Tchrist is neither 100% wrong nor 100% right. I don't know much about Catalan.

Comment: Both of them are wrong. Normative dictionaries and all kind of sources say otherwise, and can tell you that I've never heard "el tribu" and it would sound very bad. http://www.avl.gva.es/lexicval/?paraula=tribu https://dlc.iec.cat/Results?DecEntradaText=tribu&AccentSen=True http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0137291 https://dcvb.iec.cat/results.asp?Word=tribu https://aplicacions.llengua.gencat.cat/llc/AppJava/index.html?action=Principal&method=cerca_generica&tipusCerca=cerca.queSignifica&input_cercar=tribu https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribu_(antropologia)

Comment: I'll try to fix en.wikitionary (ca.wikitionary is already right https://ca.wiktionary.org/wiki/tribu ).

Comment: Very interesting. I’ve come across medieval words that have gone out of use like *geo*, now *gelo* only, or *oppoente*, now *oponente* only, that fit the same sort of pattern: the old form deviated from Latin along a common vernacular pattern (dropping between-vowels l and n in this case), and these days only a version closer to Latin survives.